# Equation $x=\phi(x)+\phi(x+1)-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve the equation $x=\phi(x)+\phi(x+1)-1$, where $x$ is a natural number and $\phi$ is Euler's totient function?

I failed even to figure out whether this equation has finite number of solutions or infinite.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems nicer to write it as y=phi(y)+phi(y-1).  What have you tried?  Can you deduce some divisibility properties of y?  Does this arise as part of a research problem?  Gerhard "Has More Questions And Answers" Paseman, 2017.06.29.

Comment: It appears that there is a lot of solutions, the number of which appears to grow logarithmically.

Comment: My belief is that the solutions of the equation, *A067798* from the OEIS, are the same that the solutions of $$x=\phi(\phi(x)+\phi(x+1)-1)+\phi(\phi(x)+\phi(x+1))-1.$$
I've tested it for the segment of integers $1\leq x\leq 10^6$. I have not studied subsequent compositions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [OEIS Sequence A067798](https://oeis.org/A067798).
Nothing else seems to be known about it; at any rate OEIS gives no
references to the literature, only a link to 
[a list of further such $x$](https://oeis.org/A067798/b067798.txt)
  from Giovanni Resta that extends it from the 43rd solution, $722015$, 
to the 76th, $1103806594815$, which is just a a bit larger than $2^{40}$.
(Thanks to **Robert Israel** for noting this link in his comment.)

It seems very hard to do anything with the problem other than make a few
elementary observations (e.g. all $x>2$ will be odd), do some heuristics
(biases mod $3$, $4$, $5$, and other small moduli; expected asymptotics),
and use yet more computing power to find a handful of further solutions.

Comment: Note that A067798 also includes a file from Giovanni Resta containing the first 76 terms, ending with 1103806594815.

Comment: Right, I saw the link but forgot to check it. I'll edit my reply to give this link  (https://oeis.org/A067798/b067798.txt) and remove my shorter list.

Comment: It would be of interest to know for these solutions if y/phi(y) stays in a narrow range.  I suspect it may be bounded over all solutions.  Gerhard "Good A Conjecture As Any" Paseman, 2017.06.29.

Comment: Is it possible that 2^(2^n) is a solution for y for infinitely many n? Gerhard "Easier Than Fermat Primes, Perhaps?" Paseman, 2017.06.29.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman That would require $\varphi(2^{2^n}-1) = 2^{2^n-1}$.  For $n \ge 6$, $2^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $641$, so $\varphi(2^{2^n}-1)$ divisible by $\varphi(641) = 640$ which is not a power of $2$.  So $2^{2^n}$ is never a solution for $n \ge 6$.

Comment: Indeed, it took me longer than it should have to come to that. Thanks for making it explicit. Gerhard "Increasing Smartness Through Dumb Questioning" Paseman, 2017.06.29.

Comment: More generally, y a solution and (y+1) prime means y^2 is a solution.  Perhaps we can thin the list to find primitive (non square) y and a way to generate them?  Gerhard "Removing Patterns To Find Patterns" Paseman, 2017.06.29.